# ngResource ($resource) is returning 404 for PUT

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

It's been a while since I've used $resource for managing my service calls.

For some reason, all my calls are working ok and reaching my REST end-points, basically /api/profile and /api/profile/:id.

But for some reason, my put returns as 404.

Anyone have an Idea of what may be going on.

Thanks and Cheers!

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chainLinkApp')

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('profile', {
    url:'/profile/:id',
    templateUrl:'views/profile.html',
    controller:'ProfileController',
    controllerAs:'profile'
  });
}])

.controller('ProfileController',['$scope', '$http', 'profileFactory', function($scope, $http, profileFactory){


  $scope.updateMode = false;


  $scope.comments = profileFactory.getProfiles.go().$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.comments = response;
  });


  $scope.getProfile = function(commentId){
    $scope.comment = profileFactory.getProfile.go({id:commentId}).$promise.then(function(response){
      $scope.comment = response;
      $scope.updateMode = true;
    }, function(error){
      return console.log('An error has occured', error);
    });
  };


  $scope.addProfile = function(comment){
    profileFactory.postProfile.go(comment).$promise.then(function(){
      console.log('Your post was a success');
      $scope.comment = {};
    }, function(error){
      console.log('There was an error: ', error);
    });
  };


  $scope.updateProfile = function(comment){
    profileFactory.updateProfile.go(comment._id, comment).$promise.then(function(response){
      console.log('Your profile has been updated');
      $scope.updateMode = false;
      $scope.comment = {};
    }, function(error){
      console.log('There is an error: ', error);
    });
  };
}])


.factory('profileFactory', ['$resource', function($resource){

  return{
    getProfiles:    $resource('/api/profile', {}, { go: { method:'GET', isArray: true }}),
    getProfile:     $resource('/api/profile/:id',{},{ go: { method: 'GET', params: { id: '@id' }}}),
    postProfile:    $resource('/api/profile', {}, { go: { method: 'POST' }}),
    updateProfile:  $resource('/api/profile/:id', {}, { go: { method: 'PUT', params: { id:'@id' }}})
  };

}]);
```

Comment: The problem probably lies in your server side, check your mapping there.

Comment: try add {_method: 'PUT'} to your request, some servers can't use real PUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of you are using `$resource` is strange, it should be like this:

```
.factory('UserService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users/:id', {}, {
        'create': { method: 'POST' },
        'update': { method: 'PUT', params: { id: '@id'} }

    });
})
```

Then you call the service like this: `UserService.create(theUserobj, function(result) { ... })`

Comment: Thanks Mavlarn. You are right. Been a while since I used it and I was trying to chain a variety of calls, including some custom calls.

Comment: OK, anyway, it seems that there is no problem in your code. Did you check the url in your update request? Which should match the code in server side. Please check the 'id' in you url.